# Installing external Chrome extension from executable without browser relauch

Tags: linux, windows, macos, google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to install an external Chrome extension from an executable (**on OS X, linux and Windows**). I am following the instructions [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions). However, it seems like installing an external extension this way requires the user to relaunch their browser, which is a huge burden on the user. Does anyone know a good way to do this (on OS X, linux and windows) without a browser relaunch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is required. Chrome will only install external extensions on relaunch.

You can't work around it.